# Access 2007 embedded Iif statement

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Using Access 2007
My table has 9 columns. I have 4 columns I need to use to select a value based on dates in 3 other columns.  In a nutshell, I need the most current cost to show in the last column (Current_Cost). I have tried several embedded Iif statements to no avail. I don’t know if I have been looking at this too long and I’m just not seeing my error or if I’m way off base.

Columns in table:

- Item Number
- Original Cost
- Original Date
- Cost 1
- Date 1
- Cost 2
- Date 2
- Cost 3
- Date 3

```sql
UPDATE MyTable 
SET Current_Cost =
    IIf([MyTable]![DATE3]>[MyTable]![DATE 2],[MyTable]![COST 3],
    IIf([MyTable]![DATE2]>[MyTable]![DATE 1],[MyTable]![COST 2],
    IIf([MyTable]![DATE1]>[MyTable]![ORIGINAL DATE],[MyTable]![COST 1],
    [MyTable]![ORIGINAL COST])));
```

- FYI - I inherited this table so please don't bash me for the way it is set up!

Comment: Remember to mark an answer as accepted if you feel it answers your question sufficiently :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think [Switch](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx) is easier to manage than a bunch of nested `IIf` expressions.

First try a `SELECT` query to work out the `Switch` logic.  I think this is close to what you're aiming for:

```sql
SELECT
    Switch
        (
            [DATE 3]>[DATE 2], [COST 3],
            [DATE 2]>[DATE 1], [COST 2],
            [DATE 1]>[ORIGINAL DATE], [COST 1],
            True, [ORIGINAL COST]
        ) AS test_expression,
    *
FROM MyTable;
```

After you have the correct `Switch` expression, you can use that in your `UPDATE`.

```sql
UDATE MyTable
SET Current_Cost =
    Switch
        (
            [DATE 3]>[DATE 2], [COST 3],
            [DATE 2]>[DATE 1], [COST 2],
            [DATE 1]>[ORIGINAL DATE], [COST 1],
            True, [ORIGINAL COST]
        )
```

Comment: I appreciate your help with this. I actually used the Switch and it worked perfectly. On top of that, I shared this with my co-worker who had also never used Switch. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, because of the multiple dates. First off: can you guarantee that the following statement always holds true for your table:

```
[ORIGINAL DATE] <= [DATE1] <= [DATE2] <= [DATE3]
```

If it does, your query will be a simple `switch` statement as per @HansUp's answer.* If it *doesn't*, then things become a little more interesting. My approach would be (and note that this will only work within the same Access database file as the query) to define a VBA function that takes two values and returns their maximum, let's call it `Max2`, then use this function to find the latest date for each row in the table, then pick the cost corresponding to that date:

```
update MyTable
set Current_Cost = switch(
  DATE3 = Max2(Max2(Max2([ORIGINAL DATE], DATE1), DATE2), DATE3), [COST 3]
, DATE2 = Max2(Max2(Max2([ORIGINAL DATE], DATE1), DATE2), DATE3), [COST 2]
, DATE1 = Max2(Max2(Max2([ORIGINAL DATE], DATE1), DATE2), DATE3), [COST 1]
, true, [ORIGINAL COST]
)
```

The `Max2` VBA function (can be defined in any module):

```
public sub Max2(v1 as variant, v2 as variant) as variant
  if v1 < v2 then
    Max2 = v2
  else
    Max2 = v1
  end if
end sub
```

By the way, why `Max2` and not just `Max4`? Reusability. You can use a function like this in many different places.

`*` You can check with a simple SQL query. You can also enforce this date order as a table `check` constraint in Access. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I am sure the dates increase.... this time. But since we will be using this code again, that might not be the case. I am HOPING I will be able to modify the table to something more usable, if the powers-that-be allow it. But if not, your approach would be better in the long run.

Comment: Sure. Remember you can create a table constraint in Access that enforces this increasing date rule. Something like `alter table MyTable add constraint MyTable_DatesMustIncrease check ([ORIGINAL DATE] <= DATE1 and DATE1 <= DATE2 and DATE2 <= DATE3)`. But you can only do this via the DAO `Execute` methods, e.g. `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's evaluate what an IIF does:

```
IIF(SOME_CHECK,true_condition,false_condition)
```

Looking at your code, we see:
If

```
[MyTable]![DATE3]>[MyTable]![DATE 2]
```

then set Current_cost to be:

```
[MyTable]![COST 3]
```

Else go on to the next check..
If

```
[MyTable]![DATE2]>[MyTable]![DATE 1]
```

then set Current_cost to be:

```
[MyTable]![COST 2]
```

Else go on to the next check..
If

```
[MyTable]![DATE1]>[MyTable]![ORIGINAL DATE]
```

then set Current_cost to be:

```
[MyTable]![COST 1]
```

Else set to

```
 [MyTable]![ORIGINAL COST]
```

So, is that what you are looking for?

If it is not, you may need to reverse your logic..  Instead of Cost 3, Cost 2, Cost 1 then change to Cost 1, Cost 2, and Cost 3..

Comment: Yeah, I see what you are saying. Thanks. I'll take a look.